# 554 5.7.1 Relay access denied

Tags: centos, email, postfix

I have been trying to fix my Postfix server, but somehow it still don't want to accept emails from any places. From gmail I get this error:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> > support@xxx
>
> Technical details of permanent failure:
>   Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient >domain xxx by mail.xxx. [ip.address.here].
>
> The error that the other server returned was:
>   554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied

This is my postfix config:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
myhostname = CHANGED HOSTNAME
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

I have been trying to find a solution for hours and I have visited and tried almost everything.

Please help me out

Comment: Dumping your configuration file on us and expecting us to fix your mail server for you is poor form old chap. [Tell us what you have tried](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault), including results of your tests (you tried locally, right? Followed the steps at http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html & http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html ?).

Comment: Check your mydestination to see if your domain (xxx in your example)  is weel recorded. There is a comma at the end of the line which is strange... Check the logs !

Comment: This is the message from logs after I restarted postfix and tried to send an email via gmail http://pastebin.com/1tkCxXPF

Comment: Is the mailbox and domain defined on this server or are you trying to relay the email to another mailbox server somewhere?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/A2t5svFj http://screencast.com/t/ngmGiB72d These areo from my Postfix admin. I'm not sure if they are correctly set up

Answer (score 1):

@Jaan Postfix will accept the mail only if the email address falls under anyone of the following address classes.

- Local domain Class
- virtual Alias Class
- Virtual mailbox class
- Relay class

Or if the connecting host is listed under mynetworks (default class). More about postfix address classes [here](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html)

Your screenshots show that you are setting up your domain xxx as local domain class. i have never used any GUI for postfix administration. Ensure the following configurations exist in main.cf

```
mydestination = xxx
# to consider xxx domain as local address class
# add localhost localhost.$mydomain also to mydestination after your testing
# valid users under mydestination domains should be specified using local_recipient_maps

#local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
# commented it out, because default setting is proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
# Now all your UNIX users and special aliases in $alias_maps can receive mails
```