# Postfix - How to send mail to any domain?

Tags: email, postfix

On my website, I allow users to enter their email and a message. My website then generates an email FROM them TO myself, which is passed along to my email provider. (The reason for this is so that it's easy to reply.)

However, postfix does not allow this by default.

Does anyone know how to modify the main.cf file to allow this? I'm starting from the default.

Error:

```
Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
```

postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mothfox.com, localhost.com, , localhost
myhostname = mothfox.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

I think somehow I need to filter based on IP, rather than on domain...

Comment: Please post your main.cf and the error message you get. Your question doesnt convey any required info

Comment: Updated question sorry about that.

Comment: Just add output of the "# postconf -n" to the question

Answer (score 0):

For eg. If you are trying to receive mail for `user@mothfox.com` The error shows that you have listed your domain name (mothfox.com) under `mydestination`, but `user` is not specified in your local_recipient_maps. Please check the answer section here. [554 5.7.1 Relay access denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/529081/554-5-7-1-relay-access-denied)
This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is really a wrong way to solve such problems. SMTP was supposed to acquire and check incoming mail, not for spoofing local messages.

I see you are using procmail to filter messages. Why not just talk directly to procmail without touching postfix?