# How can I resolve the "554 5.7.1 <external.email-address.com>: Relay access denied" error with regards to Postfix on Linux?

Tags: postfix, email-server

**Status**

Currently, my mailing situation is as follows:

`<internal.email-address.com> (i.e., on my VPS) to <internal.email-address.com>` = works :)

`<internal.email-address.com> to <external.email-address.com>` (i.e., gmail.com, outlook.com, etc.) = does not work :(

`<external.email-address.com> to <internal.email-address.com>` = works :)

**Actual problem**

When I try sending an email to anyone other than a recipient on my VPS, it fails with an error message as follows: `554 5.7.1 <external.email-address.com>: Relay access denied`

**Things I've tried**

This is the third day I am taking on this problem and have tried a whole bunch of things and read similar problems here - I am aware of [554 5.7.1 Relay access denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/529081/554-5-7-1-relay-access-denied), I've checked my main.cf and master.cf to make sure they are configured as expected, especially the relay and recepient parts, I authenticate using SASL, been tailing everything...

**Ultimately**

Postfix gets tired of trying to send off my email and returns it to me as "Undelivered Mail Return to Sender"

Comment: is your sever located at home or non business related ? if yes please use superuser.com

Comment: @djdomi The server that has the relaying issue is a VPS that is not at home and for business.

Comment: You probably need to configure [message submission](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6409) with authentication on a separate port to allow relay for the users. Otherwise it's easy to end up having an *open relay*. There's some reasoning on an [answer of mine](https://serverfault.com/a/954272). You should be able to find many tutorials on how to implement submission on Postfix.

Comment: @EsaJokinen All of what I was doing was on port 587 because I was aware that 25 could have issues, even though I know mine is open and fine. I also tried 465. I enabled these in master.cf. I have checked to make sure my server is not blacklisted too. I have tried connecting from email client (Thunderbird), CLI on my local machine and directly on the server (localhost for the VPS). With regards to port 587, I can connect to it over TLS and issue SMTP commands up until `rctp to:` and then it's `relay access denied`. Tailing Auth says `No route to host`.

Comment: You need to configure the authentication, too. See e.g. https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL

Comment: @EsaJokinen I used an smtp relay provider as a temp resolution. I am revisting the issue and will try your suggestion and do a thorough walkthrough to make make sure I am not missing anything.